# Python の class と dataclass はどう使い分ける？

Tags: python, python3

Pythonの`class`と`dataclass`はどう使い分ければよいでしょうか？(どう使い分けていますか？)
バージョンはPython 3.9.2です。

下記の記事を見ると、すべてのケースにおいてdataclassを使うほうが良いのでしょうか。

[Python3.7からは「Data Classes」がクラス定義のスタンダードになるかもしれない - Qiita](https://qiita.com/tag1216/items/13b032348c893667862a)

Comment: 参考: [What are data classes and how are they different from common classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263)

Answer (score 0):

"dataclass"を使用することで、"data"よりも簡潔にプログラムを書くことが出来ます。なぜなら、classの定義が短くなるためです。これにより、データの構造も把握しやすくなります。